# AJAX call is being invoked but does not return results onload when page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, refresh

Okay this is going to sound strange and hard to explain but here goes...

I have an AJAX call which is to be invoked when the user logs into the website, this works perfectly invoking the call through an onload call.

The problem I'm having is when I refresh the page, the AJAX function is being invoked but does not actually perform the AJAX call to the server so nothing is being returned. I then have a "Home" li element which can be clicked to call the Home page (which is the page that is being displayed upon logging in) so I click this link reloading the Home page and the function again executes perfectly with no problems.

Nothing is returned only when I refresh the page with the browser.

Can anybody hint on why this is happening?